# How did you sync DNS servers in on-premise and AWS Cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, dns, amazon-route53, hybrid-cloud

We have micro-services running in on-premises infrastructure and are planning to migrate these services one after the other to AWS Cloud. During the transition phase, we are to be in a Hybrid-Cloud infrastructure. One of the challenges that we are having to witness today is the syncing of the DNS servers in these two environments.

How did you solve this problem in your journey? You inputs are much appreciated. Any pointers to reference links to solutions are welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered Amazon Route 53 Resolver for Hybrid Clouds?

> Many organizations have both on-premises resources and resources in the cloud. DNS 
>   name resolution is essential for on-premises and cloud-based resources. For customers 
>   with hybrid workloads, which include on-premises and cloud-based resources, extra 
>   steps are necessary to configure DNS to work seamlessly across both environments.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-route-53-resolver-for-hybrid-clouds/